# Kafka error: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have a simple application that is sending a message on the topic. Below is my code:

Sender.java

```
@Component
public class Sender {

 private static final Logger LOGGER =
          LoggerFactory.getLogger(Sender.class);

      @Autowired
      private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

      public void send(String topic, String payload) {
        LOGGER.info("sending payload='{}' to topic='{}'", payload, topic);
        kafkaTemplate.send(topic, payload);
      }
}
```

SenderConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
public class SenderConfig {

@Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
  private String bootstrapServers;

  @Bean
  public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    // list of host:port pairs used for establishing the initial connections to the Kakfa cluster
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
        bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
        StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
        StringSerializer.class);

    return props;
  }

  @Bean
  public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
  }

  @Bean
  public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
  }

  @Bean
  public Sender sender() {
    return new Sender();
  }
}
```

Receiver.java

```
@Component
 public class Receiver {

private static final Logger LOGGER =
          LoggerFactory.getLogger(Receiver.class);

@Autowired
  private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;

      private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

      public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
        return latch;
      }

      @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.helloworld}")
      public void receive(String payload) {
        LOGGER.info("received payload='{}'", payload);
        latch.countDown();
      }
}
```

ReceiverConfig.java

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class ReceiverConfig {

@Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
  private String bootstrapServers;

  @Bean
  public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    // list of host:port pairs used for establishing the initial connections to the Kafka cluster
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
        bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
        StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
        StringDeserializer.class);
    // allows a pool of processes to divide the work of consuming and processing records
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "helloworld");
    // automatically reset the offset to the earliest offset
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

    return props;
  }

  @Bean
  public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
  }

  @Bean
  public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
        new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());

    return factory;
  }

  @Bean
  public Receiver receiver() {
    return new Receiver();
  }
}
```

application.yml

```
 kafka:
   bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
   topic:
      name: myTopic
 server:
    port: 9191
```

The above code works fine when I am posting to a topic that doesn't exist. It creates the topic. For an instance, in the above application.yml file, if the topic name is 'myTopic' which doesn't exist, the code works fine and the message is consumed. But if I run docker where in the docker yml I am having some topic names to create. If I try to post on those topics, I get the below Timeout exception.

```
Kafka error: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for TOPICNAME-0: 30010 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
```

I went through some posts on Stack Overflow, but they suggest increasing the timeout time, but in my case, its just one message that I am posting. So, I am not sure as to why I am getting this error.

Comment: My guess is docker assigns IP to the kafka server and localhost may no longer be valid, try changing the application.yml to have appropriate IP for the server.

Comment: Could you post your docker config? Also, how are you starting kafka in docker, i.e. just docker run, or compose up, or stack deploy?

Comment: I fixed it. It was a version mismatch. The Kafka version in my Spring Boot application was the latest one while the one being used in my docker settings was an older one. As soon as I updated my docker and docker compose on Ubuntu and ran again with the latest Kafka version, it worked. Thanks to both of you for your help.